# How is $|x|$ removed from this equation?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} |x| \frac c {(1+x^2)(\ln(e+|x|)^k)} \, dx
=  2 \int^\infty_0  \frac c {(1+x^2)(\ln(e+x)^k)} \, dx$$

For a real constant $k$ and $c$

I understand how the $2$ came about, but I am having difficulty seeing where the $|x|$ went.

Comment: $-\infty$ on the left maybe?

Comment: @Khan corrected it, thanks!

Comment: Can you tell where did you find it?

Comment: i think $|x|$ shouldn't go anywhere. It will  become $x$, that's it

Comment: This looks incorrect.  There ought to be a factor of $x$ in the numerator of the integrand on the RHS.

Comment: @MANMAID page 11 https://www.lakeheadu.ca/sites/default/files/uploads/77/images/Sedor%20Kelly.pdf

Comment: @tilper thats what I suspected too

Comment: Maybe try splitting the domain of integration into $x\geq 0$ and $x <0$.

Comment: I agree with @Khan that a factor $x$ is missing.

Comment: @kengchi When you write $\ln(e+|x|)^k$, do you mean $\ln((e+|x|)^k)$ or $\ln^k(e+|x|)$?

Comment: i think i understand what the question means now. thanks:) @dxiv

Answer (score 0):

tilper8 is right.

Split the integral into:

1) integral from $+∞$  to $0 $ (where $ |x|=-x ) +$

2) integral from $0 to +∞$ ( where |x|=x )$

In 1) change all the x's to say y Then put:

$y=-x ,dy=-dx$

to get an integral from $+∞ to 0 = - $that integral  from $ 0$ to $+∞$

and adding gives your right side but with an extra x in the numerator .

Comment: Please look at the FAQ for MathJax hints.  +oo is not $+\infty$  The formatting could be improved many ways besides that.

Comment: Here's a specific link to get you to the MathJax help: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: $\infty$ , I am trying  , Hey it worked  ,thanks